# A Perl 6 Regex to match a Perl 6 delimited comment

Tags: regex, raku

Anyone have a Perl 6 regular expression that will match Perl 6 delimited comments? I would prefer something that's short rather than a full grammar, but I rule out nothing.

As an example of what I am looking for, I want something that can parse the comments in here:

```
#`{ foo {} bar }
#`« woo woo »
say #`(
This is a (
long )
multiliner()) "You rock!"
#`{{ { And don't forget the tricky repeating delimiters }}
```

My overall goal is to be able to take a source file and strip the pod and comments and then do interesting things with the code that is left. Stripping line comments and pod is pretty easy, but delimited comments requires additional finesse. I also want this solution to be small and using only Perl 6 core so I can stick it in my dotfiles repo without having external dependencies.

Comment: Pod is processed with the rest of the file by the Perl 6 parser. You can access the processed QAST and strip whatever you want, I think.

Comment: @jjmerelo: Not so easy - I was searching for a way to reform QAST back to Python, and so far remain clueless if it is possible except doing it yourself.

Comment: I guess the difficulty with parsing delimited comments is that you also have to parse string constants? For example ``my $str = '#`( This is not a comment )'; #`( but this is a comment) ``

Comment: @jjmerelo: I want something Regex-like, not something I can pull out of the Perl 6 parser because doing that would be highly experimental and subject to change.

Comment: @håkon-hægland: That would also be an issue, but I could live with over-identifying these and worry about adding a quotelike parser to prevent that as a next step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Matching your examples

```
my %openers-closers = < { } « » ( ) >;        # (many more in reality)
my @openers         = %openers-closers.keys;  # { « ( ...
my ($open, $close);                           # possibly multiple chars

my token comment { '#`' <&open> <&middle> <&close> }

my token open {
  # Store first delimiter char:   Slurp as many as are repeated:
  ( ( @openers )                  $0* )

  # Store the full (possibly multiple character) delimiters:
  { $open = ~$0; $close = %openers-closers{$0[0]} x $0.chars }
}

my token middle {
  :my $nest-level; # for tracking nesting
  [
    # Continue if nested:  or if not at unnested end delimiter:
    [ <?{$nest-level}>     ||    <!&close> ]

    # Match either a nested delimiter:  or a single character: 
    ( $open || $close                   || . )

    # Keep track of nesting:
    { $_ = ~$0.tail; # set topic to latest match in list 
      $nest-level++ when $open; $nest-level-- when $close } 
  ]*
}

my token close { $close }

.say for $your-examples ~~ m:g / <.&comment> /
```

displays:

```
｢{ foo {} bar }｣
｢« woo woo »｣
｢(
This is a (
long )
multiliner())｣
｢{{ { And don't forget the tricky repeating delimiters }}｣
```

Hopefully the code is self-explanatory if you know Raku regexes. Please use the comments if you want clarification of any of it.

## Looking at related Rakudo source code

I wrote the above without referring to Rakudo's source code. (I wanted to see what I came up with without doing so.)

But I've now looked at the source code, which imo would be a more or less mandatory thing to do for anyone trying to do what you're trying to do and serious about understanding how well it might work in the general case.

As I starting point, I was particularly interested in seeing if I could figure out why feeding this code to rakudo (2018.12):

```
#`{{ {{ And don't forget the tricky repeating delimiters  } }}
```

yields the rather LTA (Less Than Awesome) compiler error:

```
Starter {{ is immediately followed by a combining codepoint...
```

This doesn't look directly relevant to your question but I encountered it when trying to understand the nested delimiter rules.

So when I got to this part of my answer I started by searching the Rakudo repo for "immediately followed". That led to a [`fail-terminator` method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/8095ceada8bbfb7f2840bd386f8810f81a85687c/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L219-L237) in the Raku grammar. (Perhaps not of interest to you but it is to me.)

Here's what else I found in the standard grammar that imo is directly related to what you're trying to do, or at least understanding precisely what the code says the rules are about matching comments:

- The [`` comment:sym<#`(...)> `` token](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/8cfa65901768b1a50779d9e298a898642d0e3306/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4776) that parses these comments. This leads to:
- The [list of openers](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/8cfa65901768b1a50779d9e298a898642d0e3306/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L26). This list should replace the measly 3 opener/closer pairs in my code that just match your examples.
- The [`quibble` token](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/8cfa65901768b1a50779d9e298a898642d0e3306/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L239). This seems to be a generic "parse 'quoted' (delimited) thing". It leads to:
- The [`babble` token](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/8cfa65901768b1a50779d9e298a898642d0e3306/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L119). This establishes a "start" and "stop" with this code:

  ```
    $<B>=[<?before .>]
    {
        # Work out the delimiters.
        my $c := $/;
        my @delims := $c.peek_delimiters($c.target, $c.pos);
        my $start := @delims[0];
        my $stop  := @delims[1];
  ```

The rule `peek_delimiters` is not in the Raku grammar file.

A search in the Rakudo repo shows it's not anywhere in Rakudo or Raku.

A search in NQP yields [a routine](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/5872eda8884dd8ac66d7214bf81804b41abc9d5e/src/HLL/Grammar.nqp#L240) in nqp's grammar (from which the Raku grammar inherits, which is why the `peek_delimiters` call works and why I looked in NQP when I didn't find it in Rakudo/Raku).

I'll stop at this point to draw a conclusion.

## Conclusion

You've got a regex. It might work out as you intend. I don't know.

If you end up investigating the above Rakudo/NQP code and understand it well enough to write a walk through of what quibble, babble, nibble, et al do, or discover a good existing write up (I haven't searched for one yet), please add a comment to this answer linking to it. I'll do likewise. TIA!

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer @raiph. I was trying to solve this myself, but I could not figure out how to implement the recursion correctly, so now I was delighted to see you had solved it!